# Would my proof of induction be accepted in an intro Abstract Algebra Course. Self-studying and New to proofs.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, induction, solution-verification

Hello I'm self studying and I'm also new to proofs and would like to know whether my proof is rigorous enough for a first course in Abstract Algebra.

I'm asked to proof Induction of the second kind which states that:

Suppose P(n) is a statement about the positive integers and c is some fixed positive integer. Assume

i) P(c) is true

ii) for every $m > c $, if P(k) is true for all k such that $c \leq k < m $ , then P(m) is true

Then P(n) is true for all $n \geq c $

The proof also has to use the well-ordering principle which states that:

Every nonempty subset of the positive integers has a smallest element.

My proof:

First let $M = \{x\mid x \in N \land x>c \land P(x) \text{ is false} \}$

Now we assume M is nonempty. Then by the well-ordering principle there exists a smallest element of M which we'll call $y.$ We know that $P(n)$ for all $c \leq n < y $ is true thus $P(y)$ is true by ii. This is a contradiction thus $M$ is the empty set which means that $P(n)$ is true for all $n \geq c $

I'm self-studying and do not know whether my proof would be acceptable for a intro abstract algebra class. So my questions are:

1. Is my proof correct?
2. and if it's not correct, why not and how would I prove it then?
3. and if it's correcct, is there anything you would change?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the other answer, the proof is almost correct, however I would "fix" it differently.

Namely, nothing is wrong with your set $M$ the way it is, but this only lets you conclude that $P(n)$ is true for $n\gt c$. Now (and *that* is the missing step, however trivial), you use (i), which says $P(c)$ is true too, to conclude $P(n)$ is true for $n\ge c$.

Comment: Thanks. This was also my reasoning I just didn't write it explicitly down because I thought it was trivial. So I take when writing proofs you want to be as explicit as possible even if it looks trivial?

Comment: @KevinvanYperen: How much to say explicitly depends on context and audience, and it’s certainly possible to go overboard. Here, though, you’re proving something that would be used without comment at the professional level, so the mere fact that you’re proving it indicates that considerable detail is expected, as does the context: this is part of building a set of tools fairly rigorously. And the fact that the truth of $P(c)$ is justified differently from the truth of $P(n)$ for $c<n<\min M$ is reason enough to spell it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is almost correct. Since you’re trying to prove that $P(n)$ holds for all $n\color{red}{\ge}c$, you should let

$$M=\{n\in\Bbb N:n\color{red}{\ge}c\land P(x)\text{ is false}\}\;,$$

Then, as you did, you assume that $M\ne\varnothing$ and let $m=\min M$. Then you argue that $m\ne c$, since (i) ensures that $c\notin M$, so $m>c$. Now the rest of your argument goes through just fine: the minimality of $m$ implies that $P(n)$ is true for $c\le n<m$, and (ii) then implies that $P(m)$ is true, contradicting the choice of $m$. The contradiction shows that in fact $M=\varnothing$, and $P(n)$ is therefore true for all $n\ge c$.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser. As I said in Stinking Bishop's awnser I used the same reasoning as he did I just didn't write it down. I can also see why your proof would work.

Comment: @KevinvanYperen: You’re welcome.